# I want to write a sparql query to extract from dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to use the public SPARQL endpoint over the DBpedia data set at http://dbpedia.org/sparql to "Find all Greek wines known by DBpedia and the region of Greece where they are produced".

Can you help me where and how I should start?

Comment: Explore the DBpedia schema first. If you have some examples wines that should be returned, you could have a look at those and check if there is any common information that fit's your query, e.g. check if those wines have some relationship to Greece by whatever property.

Answer (score 0):

For this degree of exploration, I'd suggest you start with the [Facet Browser](http://dbpedia.org/fct/)…

or possibly the [graphical SPARQL query builder, iSPARQL](http://dbpedia.org/isparql/)…

or maybe even the DBpedia entries for ["Wine"](http://dbpedia.org/page/Wine) or ["Greek wine"](http://dbpedia.org/page/Greek_wine).